# How to add dynamically images onto a scroll view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made a scrollview like this:

[image: scrollview]

I've made an image which is a circle 128x128 pixels, like this:

[image: circle 128x128 pixels]

What I want is to add "random" images of a certain height (multiple of 128), like this:

[image: "random" image added of a certain height]

When there's a lot of them, it might look like this:

[image: When there's a lot of them]

But as you can see, the problem is that they are ignored from the scrollbar which doesnt change.

My hierarchy is like this:

[image: my hierarchy]

The viewport object is like this:

[image: The viewport object]

And the content is like this:

[image: The content object]

I know that if you add an image as a *property* of the content, the scrollbar takes in account the actuel properties of the image. For example here, if I set the image to a big height, the scrollbar changes and that works:

[image: image as a property]

Now if I add an image into the content = as a child, this does nothing:

[image: image into the content = as a child]

What should I do so the scrollbar takes all the images that are children of the content in account?

Comment: There are two ways to do scroll-view's in Unity. 1: Manually set the `Content`'s Height via a script. This will make the scroll bar adjust accordingly..  2: Add a `Content-Size-Fitter` to the `Content` and a `Vertical Layout Group`.. Then `duplicate` each item in the `content`. This will cause the scroll view's content size to grow automatically according to the amount of items in it.  The second way is of course harder and less flexible because you cannot "position" the items the way you want them. Thus use the first way if you need customizability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do this would be to use  [RectTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors.html) to modify the `content`'s height (and width, if necessary) to the desired value.

It appears that your specific use-case will have some difficulty in arriving at the desired height, but provided you have some way of calculating it, all it takes it is calling that method. The two parameters are the sized desired (in this case, the desired height) and which direction to apply that size to (in this case, `RectTransform.Axis.Vertical`).

You might be able to do this with a [`Content-Size-Fitter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html), but I'm not familiar enough with how they work to make an accurate judgement on which might be easier or how to go about using this component.

Comment: I've already tried with `Content-Size-Fitter` but as Brandon said in the comments, you must add a `Vertical Layout Group` and provide a hard-coded height value, so this is not a viable solution. I'll try yours right now.

Comment: That works!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Ok I check your answer as valid, I just have to loop on all the children components, and get the "biggest" height value.

Comment: @OlivierPons I thought that might be what you'd have to do, but I wasn't entirely sure what your...system was. Don't forget to include the object's height-size as well (if relevant).

Comment: It's done. Not very obvious (I had to take in account localScale). But it's working now!